# rs2csvout removing data starting with <

Tags: php, mysql, csv, adodb

I am attempting to use the ADODB function of rs2csvout() to generate a CSV file directly from a SQL query.  For some reason the resulting CSV that it generates excludes data in fields that begins with the < symbol.

If I look at the output of my query directly run in the database I can see that it returns the data in full, including any that starts with <.

Why would this be?

```
$rs = $DB->Execute('SELECT   
ID as DATABASEID
,strTestcode
,strTestname
FROM testdb');

print rs2csvout($rs);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web browser is eating those because it's , well, HTML looking!

You need to use `htmlentities` in this case (just for the preview)

```
print htmlentities(rs2csvout($rs));
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  Using the htmlentities() function doesn't make a difference though.  I wonder if the rs2csvout() function is stripping them out before it outputs...?

Comment: Yeah that was it.  Inside that function there was a call to strip_tags() which was causing the problem.  I altered it to my own needs and all is working now.  Thanks!